# How can I solve an issue from my platform, where in my referral team page there is data that isn't been recorded after some functions? Value remains 0

Tags: php, html, laravel

[image]

[image]

I have a problem with my affilliate site when it comes to Personal Commission, Team Commission, Team Size, Registered Members, First Depositor and Active Members

```
    <div class="box form-box stat-box">
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Recharge</div>
                <div class="value">${{$teamrecharge}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Withdraw</div>
                <div class="value">${{$teamwid}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Personal Commission</div>
                <div class="value">$0.0000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Commission</div>
                <div class="value">$0.0000</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">LV1 Members</div>
                <div class="value">{{$team1count}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Size</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Registered Members</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">First Depositor</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Active Members</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help on how i can call and resolve soo that value doesn't remain (0) 0 in the front page

```
                   <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Personal Commission</div>
                <div class="value">$0.0000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Commission</div>
                <div class="value">$0.0000</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">LV1 Members</div>
                <div class="value">{{$team1count}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Size</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Registered Members</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">First Depositor</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Active Members</div>
                <div class="value">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How could we possibly help you, if all you give us is some screenshots and a bit of static HTML? We have no information whatsoever here what your data model even is. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

## Personal commission, team commission

```
        <div class="stat-row">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Personal Commission</div>
                <div class="value">$0.0000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="label">Team Commission</div>
                <div class="value">$0.0000</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## Team size, Registered members, First depositor, Active members

```
    <div class="stat-row">
        <!-- Some other field -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="label">Team Size</div>
            <div class="value">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stat-row">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="label">Registered Members</div>
            <div class="value">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="label">First Depositor</div>
            <div class="value">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stat-row">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="label">Active Members</div>
            <div class="value">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## The problem

Look at the `div`s whose `class` is `value` for these fields. They all have default values, so whatever you have in your model, a default value will be displayed itself, for example `$0.0000`. **Solution**: Use your model values, like you used in other fields.